# Express + body-parser + Postman: failing to parse POST body

Tags: express, postman, body-parser

As you can see in the code and the attached screenshot, my body is always sent empty, and I have no idea why. Would love some help.

Versions:

```
"body-parser": "^1.20.1",
"express": "^4.18.2"
```

Code:

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get("/blockchain", function (req, res) {});

app.post("/transaction", function (req, res) {
  console.log(req.body);
  console.log(req.body.amount);
  res.sendStatus(200);
});

app.get("/mine", function (req, res) {});

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log("Listening on port 3000...");
});
```

Screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Did you set the correct content-type header?

Comment: You need to set the dropdown on the right from text to json. This will change the content-type header as @tkausl suggested.

Comment: Note that you do not need to add `body-parser` middleware as it is already part of [express 4.x](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html): `app.use(express.json());` can replace body-parser